# Error when displaying HelloWorld web part in tenant workbench

Tags: spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

My HelloWorld web part works fine in my localhost workbench.  On my tenant workbench, I can add the web part but then I get the attached error instead of displaying it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For funsies, I tried creating a new Developer site collection in my tenant - and the web part displays just fine in that workbench.  This is contrary to what [the current documentation says](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-developer-tenant) (see below).

[image]

Comment: Created an issue for this:  https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1245